# Cumulative total with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table with 2 columns - Item and quantity. Column [item] is unique, [quantity] can have the same value.  Task: From first table make another table that contains additional column - cumulative_total.  This column is adds maximum values of column [quantity], but when cumulative_total reaches 160, you must last_value[cumulative_total] = 160, and last_value [quantity] = 160 - last_value[quantity]. When this condition is done, task is completed.

Table

| Item | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 241/20 | 126 |
| 241/3 | 94 |
| 42/30 | 84 |
| 236/30 | 80 |
| 167/30 | 72 |
| 236/20 | 68 |
| 23/30 | 64 |
| 44/30 | 62 |
| 46/30 | 60 |
| 237/30 | 54 |
| 238/30 | 52 |
| 59/20 | 52 |
| 390/40 | 50 |
| 232/25 | 49 |
| 54/25 | 48 |
| 95/30 | 48 |
| 139/30 | 10 |
| 167/20 | 10 |
| 254/30 | 10 |
| 97/30 | 10 |
| 241/40 | 8 |
| 342/40 | 8 |
| 35/20 | 8 |
| 36/20 | 8 |
| 68/30 | 8 |
| 270/30 | 6 |
| 251/30 | 6 |
| 25/30 | 6 |
| 45/30 | 6 |
| 33/20 | 6 |
| 39/30 | 4 |
| 38/20 | 4 |

Expected result:

| Item | quantity | cumulative_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 241/20 | 126 | 126 |
| 241/3 | 34 | 160 |

If it's necessary, download link .csv file (https://anonfiles.com/1855h9Rby5/task_csv)

[True result should be looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGTs1.png)
i`m stopped at moment that i`m trying to make condition for cumulative_total.

```
Set @total:= 0;
Select item,
       sum(quantity) over (ORDER BY quantity DESC) as quantity,
       if (@total:= @total + `quantity` > 160,
           @total:=160,
           @total:= @total + `quantity`
           ) as cumulative_total
FROM task
```

Comment: it sounds like maybe all you want is `(sum(quantity) over (order by quantity desc)-1) % 160 + 1`?  provide data in text form, with expected results for your data.

Comment: edited post: add expected table

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are very different DBMSs under (too) many aspects. Which of them are you using?

Comment: MySQL, my bad, in tags removed oracle

Comment: Is your output made by only two rows or is it just an example?

Comment: it is just example, it can contains anymore

Comment: Consider reducing sample data to 7-8 rows, but including a full expected output. It's difficult to understand what happens to the records that follow a capped one (`cumulative_total = 160`).

Comment: When we reaches [cumulative_total] = 160, then we should Last_value [quantity], that get into final table, 160 - last_value [cumulative_total]. 
In example - 
we get more than 160 [cumulative_total], so we are made it 160, and last_value[quantity](94) -> make 160 - last_value[cumulative_total](126) =  34

Comment: don't know what you mean by last_value in your comment or in the question.  please show, as text, a set of data and your expected results for that entire set of data.  that will help lots.

Comment: oh, are you saying the rows of output stop as soon as you hit 160, and the quantity (not the cumulative_total) of the last row may be descreased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to adjust every quantity down by the amount that the cumulative total went over 160, if any.  And remove the rows after it reached 160 in an outer query, by looking for quantities that became negative.

```
select *
from (
  select
    item,
    quantity - greatest(0, sum(quantity) over (ORDER BY quantity DESC) - 160) as quantity,
    least(sum(quantity) over (ORDER BY quantity DESC),160) as cumulative_total
  from task
) cumulative
where quantity > 0
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yUQ4dvZr)

Comment: Nice, last question, please, If i need to make the same query, but quantity from table should be between 0 and 9. How i can restrict this

Comment: Addition to prev comment, cumulative total, for numbers 0 - 9, should be not 160, but 40